# A simple SQL query doesn't work and I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: mysql

I'm really new to MySQL, trying to update a table row based on user name and row index, but it doesn't work. Tells me there's an error around 'INDEX = 54'.

INDEX is the name of the auto-incrementing primary index column.

```
UPDATE `TABLENAME`
   SET NAME = 'NAME', DESCRIPTION = 'DESC'
 WHERE USER = 'name' AND INDEX = 54
```

Actually, even:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE INDEX=30
```

doesn't work; it says:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX=30 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1"

I'm missing something basic here.

Comment: While you can get around the issue by quoting the column name in  backtics, you should consider renaming the column from INDEX to a non-reserved word.

Answer (score 4):

`INDEX` is a [MySQL reserved keyword.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) Enclose it in backquotes if you are using it as a column name:

```
UPDATE `TABLENAME`
   SET NAME = 'NAME', DESCRIPTION = 'DESC'
 WHERE USER = 'name' AND `INDEX` = 54
```

Answer (score 3):

Try quoting `INDEX`, like you quote `TABLENAME`:

```
`INDEX`
```

it may be interpreting it as a keyword. Also, you forgot to give the exact error message.

Comment: @taralex: Simple. USER is not a reserved word.

Comment: I actually would quote all suspiciously-looking identifiers, just to avoid thinking of it. That would include *all* identifiers you use here, actually :) (I would actually avoid these names in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

INDEX is a reserved word.  You probably need to place it in back-quotes:

```
UPDATE `TABLENAME`
   SET NAME = 'NAME', DESCRIPTION = 'DESC'
 WHERE USER = 'name' AND `INDEX` = 54
```

Then you need to worry about whether you should be using upper-case or lower-case or some mixed case spelling for it.

Answer (score 1):

INDEX is a reserved word. Escape it with backticks.

```
UPDATE `TABLENAME` 
    SET NAME = 'NAME', 
        DESCRIPTION = 'DESC' 
    WHERE USER = 'name' 
        AND `INDEX` = 54
```